# transformation of sensor data

Tags: c++, rotation, android-sensors, coordinate-transformation

I want to transform this data (I was told to do it from the object perspective). A list of the data is:

- `[0, -20.790001, -4.49]` make up the acceleration xyz coordinates - `accel(x,y,z)`.
- `[-0.762739, -3.364226, -8.962189]` make up angle xyz coordinates -  `angle(x,y,z)`.

I am trying to use Rodrigues’ rotation formula or linear transformation matrix for rotation? Is this different with sensor data?
I am able to read the data from `.csv`, but am unsure how to transform into C++ and how to create a matrix in C++.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What kind of transformation do you need? Can you add some clarification?

Comment: I guess a rotational transform....

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a formula for transformation of the data, you just need to apply it.  As for the matrix and creating one, there are multiple ways, either by using a double array:

```
float matrix[][] ( or matrix** if you want to use pointers )
```

or using a class (or struct, up to you) which contains the rows and columns

```
class Matrix
  float rows[]
  float columns[]
```

Good luck!

Note: just pseudo code definitely won't work out of the box, obviously